# SQL for XML Path: Can one table cell value for each row be used as tag name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, tags

I have a quite complex query which should generate XML. Problem is, for each row of this query, one of the values from select should be used as tag name.
For example if the row is like this:

columna   |  columnb  |   columnc      
value11   | value12   | value13  
value21   | value22   | value23

xml would contain something like this, for example:

<value11> value12 </value11>

so one table value is used as tag name.

Is that possible?

Comment: You can build an element using string functions for example `cast('<'+columna+'>'+columnb+'</'+columna+'>' as xml) el` and proceed on building  XML with regular FOR XML.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0):

We use the FOR XML PATH SQL Statement to concatenate multiple column data into a single row:

.RAW
.Auto
.EXPLICIT
.PATH

Comment: do you have some example code?